# Is kohana 3.1 i18n system efficient for long messages?

Tags: internationalization, kohana, message

Should I use __() function for email messages, notifications etc? Aren't 1024 characters long texts just too long for php's array hash keys? If they are, is there a better way to handle long messages translations, ensuring Validation class will work with it also?

Using label instead of a message would also be a choice but Kohana doesn't translate strings from native language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use special View templates for a big messages. For example, `views/i18n/fr/confirmation.php`, `views/i18n/default/confirmation.php` etc.